# Angular4/typescript - onclick scroll to bottom of a page

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

I have a template in my component as below and on click of this div want to scroll to bottom of the page.

```
`<section><div onclick='scrollDown()'>Goto Reports</div></section><div>`

scrollDown() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 500);
}
```

Firstly I tried to call a function from onclick and Im getting console error saying the function is not defined.

secondly I tried to call window.scrollTo function on onclick this is also not working.

how can we do this in typescript?

Comment: Now Im able to reach inside function but the scrollTo is not working? Is any function in typescript equivalent to window.scrollTo() ?

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: I have tried with ScrollToView() and its got worked.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't use the event binding properly.

`<section><div (click)='scrollDown()'>Goto Reports</div></section><div>`

Answer (score -1):

Angular has a [documentation page about User Input](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) where it explains how to bind all sorts on events.

To bind events to your component's methods you have to use the syntax

```
(event)="method($event)"
```

`$event` is optional, if you pass it you can use the event to check keyCode, preventDefault and so on.

Example

```
<button (click)="onClickMe($event)">Click me!</button>
```

Then

```
onClickMe(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Here is an official [live demo with some examples](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/user-input/stackblitz.html).